# Fuzzy text blog

Tags: bug, blog

The blog has some fuzzy text on the highlighted article blocks.

https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/?cb=1

The platform used is Windows 7 64 bit.

- Seen in Google Chrome: Versie 74.0.3729.157 (Officiële build) (64-bits)
- Seen in Avg secure browser: Version 73.0.762.88 (Official Build) (32-bit)
- Seen in Firefox: 66.0.5 (64-bit)

  [image: Fuzzy text]
- Not seen in Internet Explorer 11 (when I could it stop from crashing): Version: 11.09.9600.1826
  [image: No fuzzy]

Comment: The similar issue with "Miriam Libre" font was reported on Meta.SO two years ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357380/poor-render-of-google-font-in-blog-post